# Semantic UI Callback for tabs

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am referring this document: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/settings

As per the document I should be able to perform callbacks on tab visible.
But I am missing some points as a result of which my alert is not coming up.

Here is a working code snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXvXKG

My JS

```
$('.top.menu .item').tab({'onVisible':function(){alert("Called")}});
```

Appreciate if anybody can help me on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of Semantic UI. The documentation is for a newer version of Semantic. Consider updating to a 2.x version.

Here is a working JSFiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/xn7aref8/1/

This works in newer versions of Semantic.

```
$('.top.menu .item').tab({'onVisible':function(){alert("Called")}});
```

Comment: I agree with you @franz But if you see the examples usage
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/usage
They have done it the same way as my fiddle in the question. I also tried doing as you had instructed $('.tab').tab({'onVisible':function(){alert("Called")}}); it didnt work either.

Comment: @Cyril I took a closer look at your code. It seems like you are using Semantic 0.16.1. The current version is 2.0.5. Your code works in the latest version. See my edited answer for the working JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks! That works I was using a low version perhaps